# hidden date form element cant delete?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `calendarDateInput.js` to add dates to my form which is all working. The problem is when my page resizes to mobile and its a much smaller screen size.

At the moment the screen can move to the right due to a hidden element in the

td.calendarDateInput

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

When you click on the style it shows this grid Which I want to delete as Im not using it for this site.

The . Loads  from the `calendarDateInput.js` file ( I have tried to delete it but that does not solve the problem)

Example below

https://jsfiddle.net/timcross/sj9aronc/4/

(But can’t get the css from the js to show for some reason on JSfiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS to set display: none on the elements. There may be a more elegant "catch all" way of doing this but you get the idea...

```
#eventenddate_ID_Link{
  display: none;
}

#eventenddate_ID{
  display: none;
}

#eventstartdate_ID_Link{
  display: none;
}

#eventstartdate_ID{
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
#eventenddate_ID_Link, 
#eventenddate_ID, 
#eventstartdate_ID_Link, 
#eventstartdate_ID{
  display: none;
}
```